# Changing data source for same attribute not possible ? (in WebGL/OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader

I happen to have multiple parts in drawing for each frame that could use the same shader/program but need different data passed to `vertexShader` as `attributes`. That data is stored in different buffers, though (one having `GL_STATIC_DRAW`, other `GL_STREAM_DRAW`). The static buffer is kinda large which is why I dont want to have it all streamed from the same buffer.

**My question:**

Is OpenGL ES 2.0 / WebGL capable of using different data for the same attribute/shader setup (read from gpu memory) ?

**What have I tried ?**

I have tried to get the attributeLocation for e.g. `a_position_f4` multiple times (`bindBuffer()` used to change the buffer) and then setting `vertexAttribPointer()` each - but debugging showed that the attribute indicies are *not dependant on the bound buffer* and so changing bound buffers and en-/disabling the vertexAttributes won't lead to the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to get the attributeLocation for e.g. a_position_f4 multiple times (bindBuffer() used to change the buffer) and then setting vertexAttribPointer() each - but debugging showed that the attribute indicies are *not dependant on the bound buffer* and so changing bound buffers and en-/disabling the vertexAttributes won't lead to the desired behaviour.

Youre conclusion is wrong. The attribute locations have nothing to do with the buffers you use. They are determined at shader link time and are not tied to buffer objects in any way. The vertex attrib pointer however will always reference the *currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` (at the time of the `glVertexAttribPointer` call)*. So you should just query the attribute locations once (per program object), and then can use

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufID);
glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_loc, ...);
```

any time to specify the buffer `bufID` as the source for the attribute data for the attribute with index `attrib_loc`. (As you can see here, each attribute array may come from a different buffer, or sever or all can come from the same, that is up to you). The GL is a state machine, an this setup will stay until you change it again, so all draw calls following this statement will use that location for fetching that attribute.

Comment: Maybe I haven't clarified enough that this was exactly what I was trying. Changing buffer, then setting AttribPointer each time it should change sources. I've also tried to re-enable the vertexAttribs afterwards again, with no success what so ever.

Comment: Add the relevant parts of your source code to the question. I can tell you that in general, it will work that way. Want is wrong in your case is impossible to guess without further information.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. I was trying something new now: disabling the old vertexAttribs before resetting them:

glDisableVertexAttribArray ( userData->oldAttribLocation );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, userData->newVertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer ( userData->newAttribLocation, ...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(userData->newAttribLocation);

This works fine. If I remove the disableVertexAttribArray, it doesn't. Can you add those statements to your answer so the answer can help others when they stumble upon this later one ? Thank you!

Comment: Well, that does not really make sense, there must be more to it. You do not need to disable an attrib, set a new pointer and then re-enable it again - if it is the _same_ attribute. However, your code uses `oldAttribLocation` and `newAttribLocation`, and if they are not the same, than the old attribute will of course be fetched (it is still enabled, and its attrib pointer points to the same data as before). I still don't know what is going on in your code, but I can't update the answer the way you request it, since that is not how the GL works.